# Problems running wso2ei sample 904 - kafka inbound endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I trying out sample 904 for WSO2 EI and following the sample [guidelines](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Sample+904%3A+Inbound+Endpoint+Kafka+Protocol+Sample).

Still I'm getting the following error when starting up the runtime:

```
[2018-05-12 19:54:45,960] []  INFO - KAFKAMessageListener Creating Kafka Consumer Connector...
[2018-05-12 19:54:45,977] []  INFO - MediationStatisticsComponent Global Message-Flow Statistic Reporting is Disabled
Exception in thread "Thread-18" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logger$
        at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<init>(Logging.scala:25)
        at kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$.<clinit>(Logging.scala)
        at kafka.utils.Logging.$init$(Logging.scala:47)
        at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.<init>(VerifiableProperties.scala:27)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig.<init>(ConsumerConfig.scala:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAMessageListener.createKafkaConsumerConnector(KAFKAMessageListener.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAPollingConsumer.poll(KAFKAPollingConsumer.java:145)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKAPollingConsumer.execute(KAFKAPollingConsumer.java:116)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.kafka.KAFKATask.taskExecute(KAFKATask.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundRunner.run(InboundRunner.java:108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger$ cannot be found by kafka_2.12_1.1.0_1.0.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

Don't know my options and I ran out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Versions:
jre 1.8.0_161
wso2ei 6.2.0
kafka 2.12-1.1.0
zookeeper 3.4.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it cannot find the "Logger" class. Are you sure you copied all of the required libs to /lib (also the one mentioned in the notes section of wso2 documentation if needed)?

What you could try is to start EI with osgi console enabled and check if the class is there. The following link might help.

[OSGI](http://www.rukspot.com/osgiconsole.html)

What you could also do is to open/extract the imported jar's and see if there's the class inside.

Comment: Hi,

I added another .jar (scala-logging_2.12-3.7.2.jar) which was not in the list for running the sample. I got rid of the warning message, but the consumer isn't picking up the message. But that is another issue - so thanks!